# onClick crash (issue solved by converting int into String before using it with setText())

Tags: android

I was trying to build a very simple game where you have to click the buttons that pop (1 is pop and 0 is not pop) as fast as you can in one minute (to get the highest number of whacks possible in that timeframe). I am able to start my app and start the counter by clicking on the "start" button, but when I click on the button with a "1" the app crashes. Do you have an idea of why?

Thank you very much for your time!

This is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.whack_a_lock_022;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int cl = 0;
    int nl = 0;
    int sl = 0;
    int whacks = 0;
    int maxwhacks = 0;
    Random r;
    float random0to1;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private Button start;
    private Button cancel;
    private TextView time;

    public float numAlea() {
        return r.nextFloat();
    }

    private View.OnClickListener btnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.startButton :
                    start();
                    break;
                case R.id.cancelButton :
                    cancel();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        r = new Random();

        // Capture our button from layout
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        start.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
        time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        Button clButton = findViewById(R.id.cl);
        Button nlButton = findViewById(R.id.nl);
        Button slButton = findViewById(R.id.sl);

        // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above

        clButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cl == 1) {
                    cl = 0;
                    TextView CapsLock = findViewById(R.id.cl);
                    CapsLock.setText("0");
                    whacks++;
                    TextView NumberOfWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfWhacksView);
                    NumberOfWhacks.setText(whacks);
                    if (whacks > maxwhacks) {
                        maxwhacks = whacks;
                        TextView NumberOfMaxWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfMaxWhacksView);
                        NumberOfMaxWhacks.setText(maxwhacks);
                    }

                    pop();
                }
            }
        });

        nlButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (nl == 1) {
                    nl = 0;
                    TextView NumLock = findViewById(R.id.nl);
                    NumLock.setText("0");
                    whacks++;
                    TextView NumberOfWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfWhacksView);
                    NumberOfWhacks.setText(whacks);
                    if (whacks > maxwhacks) {
                        maxwhacks = whacks;
                        TextView NumberOfMaxWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfMaxWhacksView);
                        NumberOfMaxWhacks.setText(maxwhacks);
                    }

                    pop();
                }
            }
        });

        slButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (sl == 1) {
                    sl = 0;
                    TextView ScrollLock = findViewById(R.id.sl);
                    ScrollLock.setText("0");
                    whacks++;
                    TextView NumberOfWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfWhacksView);
                    NumberOfWhacks.setText(whacks);
                    if (whacks > maxwhacks) {
                        maxwhacks = whacks;
                        TextView NumberOfMaxWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfMaxWhacksView);
                        NumberOfMaxWhacks.setText(maxwhacks);
                    }

                    pop();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void start () {

        time.setText("60");

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                time.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish(){
                time.setText("Done !");
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();

        pop();

    }

    private void pop(){
        // Escolhe e "POPa" o botão

        // Gera número aleatório
        random0to1 = numAlea();

        if (random0to1 <= (1 / 3)) {

            cl = 1;
            Button clButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cl);
            clButton.setText("1");

        } else if (random0to1 <= 2 / 3) {
            nl = 1;
            Button nlButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nl);
            nlButton.setText("1");
        } else if (random0to1 <= 1) {
            sl = 1;
            Button slButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sl);
            slButton.setText("1");
        }
    }

    private void cancel() {
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer = null;
        }

        //Põe botões a zeros

        cl = 0;
        Button clButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cl);
        clButton.setText("0");

        nl = 0;
        Button nlButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nl);
        nlButton.setText("0");

        sl = 0;
        Button slButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sl);
        slButton.setText("0");

        whacks = 0;
        TextView NumberOfWhacks = findViewById(R.id.numberOfWhacksView);
        NumberOfWhacks.setText("0");

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/whacksView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="WHACKS"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/maxWhacksView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="MAX WHACKS"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="60"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberOfWhacksView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberOfMaxWhacksView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Crashes with:

```
09-06 12:45:53.364 13767-13767/com.example.android.whack_a_lock_022 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.whack_a_lock_022, PID: 13767
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:335)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4555)
        at com.example.android.whack_a_lock_022.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:114)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: just update `NumberOfMaxWhacks.setText(maxwhacks);` with `NumberOfMaxWhacks.setText(""+maxwhacks);`

Answer (score 0):

TextView has two `setText()` methods. One takes a CharSequence, while the other takes an int.

You have multiple instances where you're using `TextView#setText(int)`, but you're passing a number to that method, not a resource. Example:

```
NumberOfWhacks.setText(whacks);
```

You need to convert `whacks` to a String before calling `setText()`:

```
NumberOfWhacks.setText(whacks + "");
```

As a sidenote, it might be easier to make each button a global variable, and initialize them right after calling `setContentView()`.

Comment: Indeed. The issue was that the OP confused `setText(String)` and `setText(@StringRes int)`.

Comment: that's either `String.valueOf(whacks)` or `R.string.____`.

Comment: Just moved the OnClickListeners right after setContentView() as you suggested. And I've chosen to use the String.valueOf(whacks) to solve the original issue. I just updated this post with two new updates.

Comment: I almost forgot: Thank you!

Comment: You should ask separate questions for those problems.